# Error: “El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' No esta registrado en el equipo local"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un .EXE que me permite convertir un archivo de excel .xls a .csv.con el siguiente codigo:

```
        public void convertExcelToCSV(string sourceFile, string worksheetName, string targetFile)

    {
        string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;";

        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        StreamWriter wrtr = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                string rowString = "";
                for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
                {
                    rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\"_";
                }
                wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();
                wrtr.Close();
                wrtr.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

En este ejecutable funciona perfecto, me convierte el .xls a .csv. El problema esta en que puse este mismo código en una dll que luego referencio desde otra y llamo a este método, pero al hacerlo me da el error mencionado en el titulo. NOTA: todos los proyectos están en la misma versión de framework y tienen las mismas referencias.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver con un driver, igual checa en esta [pagina](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/18bc9322-bfe6-49fd-910e-fd077948615f/el-proveedor-microsoftaceoledb120-no-est-registrado-en-el-equipo-local?forum=vbes). Saludos

Comment: Gracias, ya pude resolverlo. Cambie en todos los proyectos el modo de compilación de anyCPU a x86 y funciono todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo. Cambie en todos los proyectos el modo de compilación de anyCPU a x86 y funciono todo.

Comment: Hola JaviM, me alegra que encontraras respuesta a tu pregunta. No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada cuando pase el tiempo necesario y, si es posible, añade algo más de detalle a la respuesta (¿por qué el cambio de anyCPU a x86 soluciona el problema? ¿cómo llegaste a esa solución?). Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.